# Why using autorelease when assigning a custom object to an instance variable with a setter?

Tags: objective-c, macos, memory-management

I want to assign a custom object to an instance variable.

Here is the code:
- MyController.h/.m

```
#import "CustomData.h"  
@interface MyViewController : NSViewController  
@property (retain) CustomData* theData;  

- (void)aRandomMethod; 

@end

@implementation MyViewController  
@synthetize theData;  

- (void)aRandomMethod {  

   NSData* rawData = [someOtherObject someOtherMethod];

   // option 1
   self.theData = [[CustomData alloc] initWithData:rawData];

   // option 2
   CustomData* _theData = [[Custom alloc] initWithData:rawData];

   // option 3
   self.theData = [[[CustomData alloc] initWithData:rawData] autorelease];

   // option 4
   theData = [[CustomData alloc] initWithData:rawData];

   // ... later code calls some methods on theData or _theData, not useful here.
 }
@end
```

When running the Analyze feature in Xcode, it tells me that there is a "leaked object not referenced later..." for option 1 and 2, but not for 3 and 4. It seems that I need to `autorelease` the custom object when using the setter. I know that `autorelease`needs to be used when returning an object we own in a method.

Could you explain for each option why is it wrong or right ? Thanks.

Comment: You're missing opening braces on every option line.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Option 1 is wrong, because you `alloc`'d the object in that method, so that method now owns the object, and therefore needs to `release` it. When you assign it to a property, that `retain`s it and is expected to `release` it when it's done with it.

Option 2 is wrong for the same reason. You take out the property part of it, but because you created the object with `alloc`, you're responsible for calling `release` on it in that method.

Option 3 is correct, because you've `autorelease`d it before giving it to the property, so the method no longer owns it. Note that if you used `release` here it would break, because it would `release` it before the property gets a chance to `retain` it.

Option 4 could be correct; I'm assuming it's assigning it to an ivar. It's only correct if you're later manually releasing the ivar in your dealloc method. It's generally better to go through properties though. Otherwise you run the risk of assigning another value and forgetting to `release` the existing value.

Answer (score 1):

The biggest thing to note for options 1 and 2 is that there is an alloc, and thus needs to be a corresponding release.

Option 1 is, in essence, "hidden", because the compiler auto-generates setters and getters for you. What you don't see is that, when using dot notation, you are going through the setter, which implicitly includes a retain call. Thus you are allocating the object AND retaining, giving it a retain count of 2.

Therefore, in order to make sure it is able to be properly released in the future, you must designate it to be added to an autorelease pool for the system to clean up later. This will bring the retain count to 1, and in your dealloc method you can then safely release the property.